# Angular node_modules changes in .js files does not recompile...?

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules

I was trying to implement a try/catch clause inside Angular @swimlane line-chart node_modules folder, meaning I changed their sourcecode a bit and was trying to restart my program. But somehow, the changes are not reflected on the webpage / program. I did this on a .js file, are there any hidden .ts files that get compiled to .js by default inside node_modules modules? Because I didn't see any... or do I have to recompile or do a npm install after I change some code inside node_modules folder?

Edit: I get this.activeEntries.slice() error...
I changed the code inside `..\node_modules\@swimlane\ngx-charts\release\line-chart\line-chart.component.js` and implemented a simple try-catch around the function:

```
LineChartComponent.prototype.deactivateAll = function () {
        try{
        this.activeEntries = this.activeEntries.slice();
        }
        catch(error) {};
        for (var _i = 0, _a = this.activeEntries; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
            var entry = _a[_i];
            this.deactivate.emit({ value: entry, entries: [] });
        }
        this.activeEntries = [];
    };
```

but it has no effect... or is my try...catch wrong somehow?

Comment: It should work. Make sure you edited the  correct file. But this should only be done for testing/debugging

Comment: I edited correct file, ...\node_modules\@swimlane\ngx-charts\release\line-chart\line-chart.component.js, but somehow the try-catch does not take effect...

Comment: Maybe stop and restart `ng serve`. Add a console log somewhere on top of the file to make sure it uses the correct file

Comment: I restarted with ng serve, no effect.. but this is weird: In chrome, there is a file generated under localhost:4200 (my App) called "vendor.js" where that function deactivateAll() is implemented..? I never had this file in my original directory.. Furthermore, in CHrome Console, it tells me there is a file and a function ../src/line-chart.component.ts.LineChartComponent.deactivateAll, but there is actualls no .ts file anywhere in the node_modules... I don't uinderstand this

Comment: Are you using ivy? it seems like ivy leaves a temp file around in the file system that prevents it from recompiling items it has already compiled.